# Force ofstream file flush on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-7

I'm using an `ofstream` to write data to a file. I regularly call `flush` on the file but the backing file doesn't always get updated at that time. I assume this is related to an OS-level cache, or something inside the MSVC libraries.

I need a way to have the data properly flush at that point. Preferably written to disc, but at least enough such that a copy operation from another program would see all data up to the flush point.

What API can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will flush the Windows write file cache and write it to a file. Be aware it can be very slow if called repeatedly.

I also found this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505) article which describes the use of [_commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685%28VS.80%29.aspx)(). This might be more useful to you since you are using ofstream.

```
CXXFileBuf.flush();
_commit(CXXFileBuf.rdbuf()->fd());
```

Comment: There is no such `fd` function in the stl streams...?

Comment: what's up with `->fd` anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
MyOfstreamObject.rdbuf()->pubsync();
```

I'm using stl_port on Win 7 with ICC 9.1.

I have not tested the solution extensively but it seems to work... Maybe it could solve the problem of the absence of fd() noticed by edA-qa mort-ora-y .

Answer (score 1):

Just add `commode.obj` to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies in the project's Property Pages in Visual Studio and call `std::ostream::flush()`. That way std::ostream's flush will link against another method which has the desired behavior. That's what helped to me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a windows-only solution, you might want to use [`FlushFileBuffers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This means you will have to re-write some of your code to accomodate calls to `CreateFile()`, `WriteFile()`, etc. If your application depends on many different `operator<<` functions, you can write your own [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/).

You also might want to read the remarks section carefully. In particular,

> Due to disk caching interactions within the system, the `FlushFileBuffers` function can be inefficient when used after every write to a disk drive device when many writes are being performed separately. If an application is performing multiple writes to disk and also needs to ensure critical data is written to persistent media, the application should use unbuffered I/O instead of frequently calling `FlushFileBuffers`.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that they require unbuffered mode to be properly sized and aligned chunks. Too bad really. I'll have to call FlushFileBuffers repeatedly.